# How to programmatically handle objects in Xtext

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I have a grammar defined like:

```
Key:
    name=ID;
Step:
    name+=[Key]+;

@Override terminal ID:
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '-' | '0'..'9')
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | ' ' | '-' | '0'..'9')+;
```

And my input is:

```
When I open window Kitchen Window
Then I (see) Beautiful Garden
```

The question: How to programmatically handle input and split it to Key references in some internal rules. 
4example In first string I want it to be:

```
    [When] [I open window] [Kitchen Window]
```

And the second to be:

```
    [Then] [I] [(see)] [Beautiful Garden]
```

I don't know how to split it until it reached scope or linker and should make a decision somewhere in the code. Where should I do it?